# Pass data back to a component in React JS

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-props

I have 2 components,

Components:

- DeveloperComponent
- Launcher Component

In this, Launcher Component is called first.From that on button click it routes to Developer component. I want to pass a value back from Developer component to Launcher component.

```
  class LauncherApp extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.developerMode = this.developerMode.bind(this)
      }

    developerMode(){
        this.props.history.push('/dev') //routes to developer component
       }

    render() {
       return (
    <div>
             <List>
                <ListItem
                onClick={this.developerMode}>Developer<ListItem/>
             </List>
    </div>
     );
  }
      }
```

Developer.js

```
    class DeveloperMode extends Component {
          constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
            this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
               this.state = {
                  url:'Prod'
                };
          }

           handleChange(event) {
            this.setState({
              url: event.target.value
            });
          } 
            handleSubmit(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var env=this.state.url;
              this.props.signOut();
             }

render() {
      return(
        <div>
          <h3>Select Environment </h3>
        <RadioButtonGroup name="selectURL" defaultSelected="Prod"  onChange={this.handleChange}>
          <RadioButton
            value="Prod"
            label="Production"

          />
          <RadioButton
            value="Dev"
            label="Development"

          />
          <RadioButton
          value="Test"
          label="Testing"

        />
        </RadioButtonGroup>
        <RaisedButton label="Save" onClick={this.handleSubmit}/>
        </div>
      );
    }
        }
```

I want to get the url value in component Launcher. Please help me with this scenario.

Comment: what is your html(div) structure of the two component

Comment: Are you unmounting the `LauncherComponent` on redirecting to `DeveloperComponent`? Based on this I would have to provide different approach. Also can you provide more of your code or provide stackblitz version of a part of your code.

Comment: @Root I have updated it

Comment: @AkshayM Launcher component is the route component

Comment: Are you unmounting the LauncherComponent on redirecting to DeveloperComponent?

Comment: @AkshayM No its routing to developer component

Comment: I have make an answer, hope it helps you@SubinT

Answer (score 0):

You can send data using routing function like this,

```
this.props.history.push({pathname:'/',url:this.state.url})
```